# Which resource to use(from chef) to "run .reg files" on windows 2008 platform?

Tags: windows, powershell, resources, registry, chef-recipe

I am new to chef and wanted to know how to code for a basic step to Download and Run ‘security.reg’ file from repository for a windows OS.

- Should i use a windows_package resource ?
- If not please guide me how to run a .reg file ?
- Can I run a .reg file using a PowerShell cmdlet?

Comment: Keep in mind : i dont want to know how to do server hardening . Just how to run a .reg file on CHEF & which type of RESOURCE should i make use of to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to import a .reg file is to use the [`reg.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx) utility:

```
reg import "C:\path\to\your.reg"
```

Another option would be `regedit.exe`, which can also be used to import .reg files non-interactively:

```
regedit /s "C:\path\to\your.reg"
```

The [parameter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/82821) `/s` is to suppress the confirmation dialog that would otherwise appear.

Both programs are shipped with windows. Beware, though, that depending on your environment they may be disabled via group policy.

There is no special PowerShell cmdlet for importing files into the registry, but the above commands can be run from PowerShell as well, for instance using the call operator:

```
& reg import 'C:\path\to\your.reg'
```

Answer (score 0):

So depending on Ansgars answer I used the resource batch to run a .reg file on a Windows platform like

```
batch 'run_reg_file' do
  code 'reg import regdata.reg'
  cwd <insert path to .reg-file>
  action :run      
end
```